# Let $R$ be a P.I.D. and let $a \neq 0$ be an element in $R$. Prove that for a prime element $p$, $p(R/(a)) = ((p) + (a))/(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, quotient-group

Let $R$ be a P.I.D. and let $a \neq 0$ be an element in $R$. Prove that for a prime element $p$, $p(R/(a)) = ((p) + (a))/(a)$.

This is something that came up while reading Dummit and Foote's textbook page 466, Chapter 12.1 Lemma 8's proof. The author says that "note first that $p(R/(a))$ is the image of the ideal $(p)$ in the quotient $R / (a)$, hence is $(p) + (a)/ (a)$. I completely get that "$p(R/(a))$ is the image of the ideal $(p)$ in the quotient $R / (a)$" but I am not sure how it follows that $p(r/(a))$ "hence is $(p) + (a)/ (a)$". Shouldn't it be $(p)/(a)$ instead? I tried looking at the specific example of when $R = \mathbb Z$ and $p$ is a prime number, yet I am having difficulty seeing that it immediately follows the "hence is $(p) + (a)/ (a)$" part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It can't be $(p)/(a)$ unless $(p)$ contains $(a)$. The image equals the image of the smallest ideal that contains both $(p)$ and $(a)$, because everything in $(a)$ maps to $0$.

Comment: Prove that for **any** ring $R$, if $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then the image of $I$ in $R/J$ equals the image of $I+J$, which is $(I+J)/J$ by the Isomorphisms Theorems. This has nothing to do with $p$ being prime or $R$ being a PID.

Comment: What is $p(R/(a))$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for your comment. Can you further clarify why the image of $I + J$ is, how an isomorphism theorem is used?

Comment: @user264745 $p(R/(a))$ is $\{ p \cdot (r + (a)) \mid r \in R \}$ which is the same as $\{ pr + (a) \mid r \in R \}$

Comment: I cannot be any clearer than point you to the lattice isomorphism theorem, unless you expect me to prove it for you, which I wont. Also, "why the image of $I+J$ is" is not even a grammatical statement.